# Split PHP String of a URL

Tags: php, regex, string, url, explode

How can i return just the `TLD` of a domain name

for example, if i had the following:

`www.domain.co.uk` i want to return just the `.co.uk`

and the same for `domain.co.uk`

and the same for all other `TLDs` `(.com, .co, .org etc)`

Is there an easy way to do this in PHP without using `Regex`

I was thinking of using `explode` but im not too familiar with that

Comment: it will not help. @MangeshSatheIND

Comment: parse_url will give you domain name & then performing regular expression on it, you can get expected .com /.co.uk etc..

Comment: OP already have domain name

Answer (score 2):

You can use a library called `tldextract.php`.

Find it here https://github.com/data-ac-uk/equipment/blob/master/_misc/tldextract.php

Usage is very simple:

```
$extract = new TLDExtract();
$components = $extract('http://forums.bbc.co.uk/');
echo $components['tld']; // co.uk
```

Now how simple was that?

If you read the code, you can see that it uses a large [list](https://publicsuffix.org/list/effective_tld_names.dat) of tlds in the `fetchTldList()` function.

Comment: While this answer (in the background) is utilizing regex, the provided resource (publicsuffix.org) is incredibly helpful! +1

Answer (score 1):

```
$returnHostName = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) //it will retrun 'domain' in your case
$returnArrayType = explode($returnHostName, $returnHostName); //explode it from string 'domain'
```

Okay now the variable **returnArrayType** contain your desired output but in the form of array you can get it from calling it's index.

check if It will work.

Answer (score 1):

Not regex, not parse_url() will not help you.

You need library that extacts TLD using [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/), I recomend to use [TLDExtract](https://github.com/layershifter/TLDExtract).

Answer (score 0):

This function work to www and not-www domain name. Not working to subdomains. For better results you need to use a regex or a library.

```
    $domain = "www.domain.co.uk";
    function tld($domain)
    {
        if (strstr('www', $domain)) {
            $part = 3;
        } else {
            $part = 2;
        }
        $expld = explode('.', $domain);
        if (count($expld) > $part) {
            return $expld[count($expld) - 2] . '.' . $expld[count($expld) - 1];
        } else {
            return $expld[count($expld) - 1];
        }
    }
```